# How to authenticate user with token in yii

Tags: web-services, authentication, yii

I am using webservices in my application. First i authenticate user with username and password in each and every action.
First called login action then other create actions. and it works successfully. Because of security issue i want token base login authentication.
i want to authenticate user with token.
I spend one day for solve this issue but i cant find any proper solution. There is always issue about authentication. i cant access any action without passing through login action.
Can somebody help me? How to authenticate user with token?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by token. This might be the solution you're looking for: https://github.com/codemix/oauth2yii/blob/master/docs/server.md

Comment: token mean, once user login successfully we give token to user. so for next time user give token in post request, and i have to check if token is valid then user is granted for further access.

Comment: Without looking at details of your implementation it is difficult to comment. However, from you description it looks like the access control on the actions could be letting you down. You might want to look at changing the access control rules from authenticated (which I assume) to a custom one. See if this page helps : http://chris-backhouse.com/yii-user-defined-rules-for-access-rights/475

Comment: yup Thanks for help. i want to change access rules and i have done with it. :)